# The runtime parameter of nodejs14.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, aws-cdk-java

In which version of monocdk changed the log retention node runtime version from 14 to 20

Getting following error-

The runtime parameter of nodejs14.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs20.x) while creating or updating functions.

#aws-cdk , #monocdk

A working version of monocdk

Comment: What's "monocdk"?

Comment: I am also seeing this error when tying to deploy a Blazor Wasm website from Visual Studio 2022.  It seems to be creating an invalid cloudformation file (old version of nodejs) and so  the stack fails on 

`CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::Function                           | Custom::S3AutoDeleteObjectsCustomResourceProvider/Handler  Resource handler returned message: "The runtime parameter of nodejs14.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs20.x) while creating or updating functions.`

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monocdk) is the package, it seems to be deprecated. I would try to migrate off of that package if possible. If not, it is either an issue internal to the package or a lambda you are building. Either way look through your codebase and the codebase of the package, find where it is using NODE_14.X and update it to NODE_20.X or newer.